# Jmeter array Response, getting the sum and extracting

Tags: api, jmeter, response

Hello does anyone know how to simulate this scenario.

Example response:
{
"data": "[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]",
"success": true,
"message": {
"code": "S",
"message": "Get Count Success"
}
}

I want to add all data values and extract that. Note: the data value is dynamic sometimes the content 3 sometimes 5 and etc.

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of the request which returns the above JSON
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

   def data = new JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()).data

   def numbers = new JsonSlurper().parseText(data)

   def sum = numbers.sum()

   log.info('Sum of numbers is: ' + sum)

   vars.put('sum', sum as String)
   ```
3. That's it, you will be able to access the sum of all numbers in "data" attribute as `${sum}` where required. Also the sum will be printed to [*jmeter.log* file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging):

   [image]

More information:

- [JsonSlurper](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Thanks your command above is working what if I want to add a formula example the response is 28 and I want to multiple to 3?

Will add inside the array and multiple to 3

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Change `def sum = numbers.sum()` to `def sum = numbers.sum() * 3`

Comment: I'm encountering an error using this response



{
 "timestamps": ["2021-04-15T11:39:00Z", "2021-04-15T11:40:00Z"],
 "properties": [{
  "values": [1, 2, 3],
  "name": "Value.Restricted",
  "type": "Long"
 }],
 "progress": 100.0
}

I want to simulate above scenario on values parameter